# Bootstrap form alignment, won't pull right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that does not want to align itself.

I have tried to show lines how I want the alignment on the attached image, hope it helps.

I want the right hand textboxes to pull-right (as per the blue line on the image, does not work when i add it to the class), and the drop down boxes to fill so that they are the same size as the textboxes (as per the green lines on the image).

[image]

Code below :)

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 75px;">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">

                <h2>Ansök nu och spara tusentals kronor</h2>

                Fyll i dina uppgifter och jämför lån från Sveriges ledande banker. Du kan låna upp till 500 000kr från 3,5% i ränta.<br />
                <br />

                Endast en kreditupplysning görs genom Conteo, men sin ansökan om lån skickas till alla våra samarbetsbanker. En budgivning mellan bankerna påbörjas och du får resultatet inom 24 timmar.


            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-2</div>
            <div class="col-md-5">

                <div class="loan-form">

                    <h3>Hur mycket vill du låna?</h3>
                    <div>
                        <b>Lånebelopp</b><span class="pull-right"><span style="font-weight: bold;" id="loanamount">100 000</span> kr</span><br />
                        <div id="mainloan_slider"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <b>Återbetalningstid</b><span class="pull-right"><span style="font-weight: bold;" id="repaymenttime">8</span> år</span><br />
                        <div id="repaymenttime_slider"></div>
                    </div>

                    <br />

                    <hr style="background-color: #E6C485; height: 2px;" />

                    <div class="form-inline">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox" placeholder="förnamn"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox pull-right" placeholder="efternamn"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px;">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox" placeholder="personnummer"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox pull-right" placeholder="email"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px;">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox" placeholder="hemnummer"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox pull-right" placeholder="mobilnummer"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px;">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCivilstand" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Gift" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Singel" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Skild" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Änka/Änkeman" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Separerad" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddEmploymentType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Annat" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Fast anställd" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Egen företagare" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Visstidsanställd" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Pensionär" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Student" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Arbetslös" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px;">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddChildren" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAccomnodationType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Annat" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Hyresrätt" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Bostadsrätt" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Inneboende" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Villa/Radhus" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px;">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" CssClass="form-control loan-form-textbox" placeholder="boendekostnad"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnApply" runat="server" Text="Ansök nu" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>



            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap columns have padding on right and left sides, this means that aligning to the right will not be at the edge. to align to the right edge, add `style="padding-right: 0;"` to elements you need pulled right (it would be better if you use a class rather than inline code `.col-pull-right{padding-right: 0;}`

The box sizing problem should be solved by removing form-inline class at

```
<div class="form-inline">
```

Here the full code. Note i have used final html elements for the code above.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 75px;">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">

                    <h2>Ansök nu och spara tusentals kronor</h2>

                    Fyll i dina uppgifter och jämför lån från Sveriges ledande banker. Du kan låna upp till 500 000kr från 3,5% i ränta.<br />
                    <br />

                    Endast en kreditupplysning görs genom Conteo, men sin ansökan om lån skickas till alla våra samarbetsbanker. En budgivning mellan bankerna påbörjas och du får resultatet inom 24 timmar.


                </div>
                
                <!-- can be replaced by col-md-offset-2 on element below it -->
                <div class="col-md-2">.col-md-2</div>
                <div class="col-md-5">

                    <div class="loan-form">

                        <h3>Hur mycket vill du låna?</h3>
                        <div>
                            <b>Lånebelopp</b><span class="pull-right"><span style="font-weight: bold;" id="loanamount">100 000</span> kr</span><br />
                            <div id="mainloan_slider"></div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div>
                            <b>Återbetalningstid</b><span class="pull-right"><span style="font-weight: bold;" id="repaymenttime">8</span> år</span><br />
                            <div id="repaymenttime_slider"></div>
                        </div>

                        <br />

                        <hr style="background-color: #E6C485; height: 2px;" />
                        
                        <!-- remove class form-inline from here -->
                        <!--<div class="form-inline"> -->
                        <div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input ID="txtFirstname" class="form-control loan-form-textbox" placeholder="förnamn"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input ID="txtLastname" class="form-control loan-form-textbox pull-right" placeholder="efternamn"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px;">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input ID="TextBox3" class="form-control loan-form-textbox" placeholder="personnummer"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input ID="TextBox4" class="form-control loan-form-textbox pull-right" placeholder="email"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input ID="TextBox1" class="form-control loan-form-textbox" placeholder="hemnummer"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input ID="TextBox2" class="form-control loan-form-textbox pull-right" placeholder="mobilnummer"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px; padding-right: 0">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select ID="ddCivilstand" class="form-control loan-form-textbox">
                                        <option value=""> Gift</option>
                                        <option value=""> Singel</option>
                                        <option value=""> Skild</option>
                                        <option value=""> Änka/Änkeman</option>
                                        <option value=""> Separerad</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select ID="ddEmploymentType" class="form-control loan-form-textbox">
                                        <option value=""> Annat</option>
                                        <option value=""> Fast anställd</option>
                                        <option value=""> Egen företagare</option>
                                        <option value=""> Visstidsanställd</option>
                                        <option value=""> Pensionär</option>
                                        <option value=""> Student</option>
                                        <option value=""> Arbetslös</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select ID="ddChildren" class="form-control loan-form-textbox">
                                        <option value=""> 1</option>
                                        <option value=""> 2</option>
                                        <option value=""> 3</option>
                                        <option value=""> 4</option>
                                        <option value=""> 5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select ID="ddAccomnodationType" class="form-control loan-form-textbox">
                                        <option value=""> Annat</option>
                                        <option value=""> Hyresrätt</option>
                                        <option value=""> Bostadsrätt</option>
                                        <option value=""> Inneboende</option>
                                        <option value=""> Villa/Radhus</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:25px;">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input ID="TextBox5" class="form-control loan-form-textbox" placeholder="boendekostnad"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <button ID="btnApply" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Ansök nu</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>



                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: added my testing code. consider using `form-group` class with `col-sm-6` to properly space the input fields on small screens.